# AttributeError: 'HTTPHeaderDict' object has no attribute 'get_all' while mapping the mappings in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Here I have added my code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Date, Integer, Keyword, Text
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections

# Define a default Elasticsearch client
connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'])

class Article(Document):
    title = Text(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
    body = Text(analyzer='snowball')
    tags = Keyword()
    published_from = Date()
    lines = Integer()

    class Index:
        name = 'blog'
        settings = {
          "number_of_shards": 2,
        }

    def save(self, ** kwargs):
        self.lines = len(self.body.split())
        return super(Article, self).save(** kwargs)

    def is_published(self):
        return datetime.now() >= self.published_from

# create the mappings in elasticsearch
Article.init()
```

Here I am adding my `elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch_dsl`
versions:

1. `elasticsearch==7.8.0`
2. `elasticsearch_dsl==7.0.0`

The error I have got from the code:

```py
AttributeError: 'HTTPHeaderDict' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 9):

For me it got fixed by upgrading *urllib3* lib.

The *elasticsearch* lib was upgraded from 6.x to 7.x some days ago and *urllib3* version was 1.24.1.

An upgrade to 1.25.10 fixed it.